# How to enable keyboard in tablet mode (HP Spectre x360)

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, tablet

HP Spectre x360 laptops have a hinge screen that can turn 360 degrees. It can be folded to imitate a tablet, for example. When you **do** fold it, Ubuntu enters its *tablet mode* -- keyboard and touch-pad will be disabled.

I want to stop that. I'd like to keep keyboard and touch-pad on so that I could connect to an external display and still be able to use them. I've done some googling and found a few solutions:

- On Windows, you can do this by disabling the Inter(R) Integrated Sensor Solution driver. I have Windows installed parallel to Ubuntu, so I tried doing that. It helped solve the problem while I'm in Windows, however, when I go back to Ubuntu, the problem remains.
- On Ubuntu, people generally recommend using the `xinput` command to control input devices (e.g. inable/disable them). But it doesn't seem to reflect the real state of affairs... For example, right now I'm typing this using an external keyboard and mouse; embedded keyboard and touch-pad are *de-facto* disabled -- I cannot use them -- as the screen is folded and tablet mode active. Yet, if I run `xinput` and check the `props` of my touch-pad, it reports it as being enabled.

Here are some snippets from of `xinput` betraying me... :)
As you can see on the second snippet it says `Device Enabled (154): 1` which is a plain lie. Trying to run `xinput --enable 18` anyways gives nothing -- touch-pad stays disabled.

```bsh
sharpvik@sharpvik:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control      id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0732:00 04F3:24DB                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ COMPANY USB Device                        id=22   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard System Control        id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision FHD RGB-IR: HP Tr           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ELAN0732:00 04F3:24DB                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control      id=21   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SEMICO USB Keyboard                       id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

```bsh
sharpvik@sharpvik:~$ xinput --list-props 18
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (154):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (156): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (299): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (300): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (301):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (302):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (303):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (304):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (305):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (306):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (291):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (292):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (307):    0
    ...
```

Another program, `acpi_listen` seems to catch that moment of folding the screen. It prints `video/tabletmode TBLT 0000008A 00000000` every time I do that. Although I am not sure as to how to use that to resolve the issue.

It seems like the problem is deeper, at the hardware level, but I'm not an expert yet, so I'm asking for help. How can I prevent keyboard and touch-pad from being disabled?

Comment: Any updates on this? Same issue here with Thinkpad Yoga. I thought of generating that acpi event manually, but no progress there yet.

Comment: HP ENVY x360 Convertible 13m-ag0xxx
Windows 10 Home 64-bit Also wanted to use my keyboard after flipping my screen over backwards. What worked for me was going into Device Manager > System Services > AMD Sensor Fusion Hub > (Disable device)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late, but I had this exact problem on my HP envy x360 laptop as well. I followed the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226628/17577) (disabling some kernel driver modules that the sensor uses to detect folding) and was successful. Let me know if this works for you too!

Comment: I have a hp pavillion x360 and I didn't do anything, I just touched a typing area and it worked.

Comment: @rodude123 So you can use the keyboard and type while the laptop is completely folded without going through all of those steps? That is interesting since in the answer I referenced, the device used was an HP Pavilion x360.

Comment: Yea works for me all i have to do is click on an input box like the search box on Google

Comment: which kernel driver modules did you disable? Seems like disabling all of the mentioned in that answer is an overkill. (thinkpad yoga, same issue here)

Comment: @Ayrat I had actually blindly used the entire list. Let me see if I can find out more about each of these modules and determine which ones are strictly necessary. I am guessing it won't be the same for all laptop models/manufacturers though.