# Keyboard and touchpad doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop with a replaced display panel (very crucial info). When on Windows 10, I had to disable the Intel Integrated Sensor Hub device for the keyboard and trackpad to work (presumably because the laptop thought it was in tablet mode when it wasn't due to the sensor board being unplugged internally because the replacement display isn't a touchscreen)

How can I do the same on Linux to make my built-in keyboard and trackpad work again? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it myself with some help from Tyler's Tech, here's the list of kernel modules to disable for keyboard and trackpad functionality with a replacement touchscreen:

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ish.conf`

```
blacklist hid_sensor_rotation
blacklist hid_sensor_incl_3d
blacklist hid_sensor_magn_3d
blacklist hid_sensor_gyro_3d
blacklist hid_sensor_accel_3d
blacklist hid_sensor_trigger
blacklist hid_sensor_iio_common
blacklist industrialio_triggered_buffer
blacklist industrialio
blacklist hid_sensor_custom
blacklist hid_sensor_hub
blacklist intel_ishtp_loader
blacklist intel_ishtp_hid
blacklist intel_ish_ipc
blacklist cros_ec_ishtp
blacklist intel_ishtp
```

Save this file as root and run `sudo update-initramfs -u` then reboot. Your keyboard and trackpad should work. Note that this is for my HP Pavilion x360, your millage may vary. You can use `lsmod` to find out more modules to disable for your laptop.

Comment: Hi, could you provide some information about how you decided which modules to disable, and a link to your source from "Tyler's Tech"? Did you just use trial and error? I have a similar 2-in-1 HP laptop (the Elite Dragonfly Max). I tried your blacklist but my keyboard and touchpad still get disabled in tablet mode. I have not replaced any components like the OP, but I would just like to be able to fold up my laptop while at home and plug in to an external monitor but still use the onboard keyboard and touchpad.

Comment: @CaseyJones I used trial and error. I did this a while back (and I no longer use that laptop) so I can't really recall exactly which module does what, but those modules are responsible for the movement sensors on the laptop. Tricks the OS into thinking it isn't a convertible.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: Wow it works alright on my HP Spectre x360. I didn't bother narrowing down each module though.