# Using keyboard and touchpad of HP Envy x360 when the device is in tablet mode

Tags: drivers, keyboard, touchpad, hp

Like I said in the title - I pretty much want to use my laptop with and external monitor and still be able to use the keyboard and touchpad of my device. This works as long I use it in "normal laptop mode", but the monitor of my laptop has stopped working ages ago and I have no intention to replace it. It's just in the way and I would very much prefer to have it "flipped around" so it sits under the other hardware, directly on the table. (I have considered removing it completely, but I am a complete novice when it comes to tinkering with hardware so I'd rather not risk "ruining" the laptop further.)

I used it like this back when I still had windows installed, there was a pretty straightforward solution back then, since this was the OS hp intended it to be used with I guess. But windows at some point made the device unusable, it crashed constantly which is why I made the switch to Ubunutu and I have to say I am baffled how everything just runs smoothly now... except for this one small problem with the keyboard that is.

WHAT I TRIED:

Followed this solution: [Keyboard and touchpad doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226536/keyboard-and-touchpad-doesnt-work/1226628#1226628)

( This person also seems to have pretty much my problem but there is no different solution:
[How to enable keyboard in tablet mode (HP Spectre x360)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174454/how-to-enable-keyboard-in-tablet-mode-hp-spectre-x360) )

...didn't work for me.

WHAT I TRIED TO MAKE SURE I DIDN'T JUST MESS UP:

- I realize that my laptop is a different model, but looking through all the modules using `lsmod` all the ones that I put in file to blacklist were there, exact same name as in the instructions.
- I edited the `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.config` file which was the closest sounding I found, there was no blacklist-ish.config but I figured it would be fine...?
- I edited and saved the file it with `sudo nano` and that all seemed to work fine. I checked what "save as root" meant (pretty much that I had put in my password to open and edit the file in nano I guess?)
- I ran the `update-initramfs -u` command, which at first I wasn't sure if it had worked, but I ran it again with verbose output and it seemed to do its thing (whatever that thing it's doing is... I am somewhat of a beginner, if that isn't apparent)
- I rebooted the system and unfortunately nothing had changed. I checked if the file had really been saved, I checked the manual for `initramfs` to see if I had done that step correctly, and as far as I can tell, I did.

This is the first time I am reporting a problem on the askubuntu board, so please if there is any additional information that I could give, that would help people here to help me solve this problem, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you run "lsmod" and add the contents to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm pretty much a novice at Linux I'm not really sure how to go about it configuration wise, but it shouldn't be to hard to remove the display altogether. You can watch a teardown like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj1nepZBZzE) on youtube and if you're comfortable enough closely follow the steps of the disassembly or you could ask someone more experienced to do it for you; a PC technician probably won't charge that much for a job like this.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind when I set the bounty, but that ought to do the trick in this particular instance. Thanks!